# Invoke-command and running ps1 with parameters

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to run a script using invoke-command to install defender for endpoint with some associated parameters.

If I run a standard ps1 using invoke-command it works with no issues. However,  if I run the following:

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName NAME -FilePath \\srv\share\install.ps1 -OnboardingScript \\srv\share\WindowsDefenderATPonboardingscript.cmd -Passive
```

I receive "A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'OnboardingScript'". Can someone please help me understand how I invoke a command and run a script with parameters?

Parameters already defined in the install.Ps1 file

https://github.com/microsoft/mdefordownlevelserver/blob/main/Install.ps1

Comment: Basically, `Invoke-Command` is complaining because you're trying to pass arguments it doesn't have (`-OnboardingScript` and `-Passive`). These arguments should be passed through `-ArgumentList`

Answer (score 2):

Your [`Invoke-Command`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/invoke-command) call has a *syntax problem*, as [Santiago Squarzon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15339544/santiago-squarzon) points out:

**Any *pass-through* arguments** - those to be seen by the script whose path is passed to `-FilePath` - **must be specified via the `-ArgumentList` (`-Args`) parameter, as an *array***.

```sh
# Simplified example with - of necessity - *positional* arguments only.
# See below.
Invoke-Command -ComputerName NAME -FilePath .\foo.ps1 -Args 'bar', 'another arg'
```

The **same applies** to the more common invocation form that uses a script block (`{ ... }`), via the (potentially positionally implied) **`-ScriptBlock` parameter**.

However, there's a catch: **Only *positional* arguments can be passed that way**, which:

- (a) requires that the target script support positional argument binding for all arguments of interest...
- (b) ... which notably precludes passing *switch* parameters (type `[switch]`), such as `-Passive` in your call.
- (c) requires you to pass the invariably positional arguments in the correct order.

---

**Workaround**:

Use a `-ScriptBlock`-based invocation, which allows for regular argument-passing with the usual support for *named* arguments (including switches):

- If, as in your case, the **script file is *accessible by a UNC path visible to the remote session as well***, you can simply call it *from inside the remote script block*.
- Note: It isn't needed in your case, but you generally may need [`$using:` references](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_scopes#the-using-scope-modifier) in order to incorporate values from the *local* session into the arguments - see further below for an example.

```sh
Invoke-Command -ComputerName NAME {
  & \\srv\share\install.ps1 -OnboardingScript \\srv\share\WindowsDefenderATPonboardingscript.cmd -Passive
}
```

- **Otherwise** (typically, a **script file *local to the caller***):

Use a `$using:` reference to pass the *content* (source code) of your script file to the remote session, parse it into a script block there, and execute that script block with the arguments of interest :

```sh
$scriptContent = Get-Content -Raw \\srv\share\install.ps1
Invoke-Command -ComputerName NAME {
  & ([scriptblock]::Create($using:scriptContent)) -OnboardingScript \\srv\share\WindowsDefenderATPonboardingscript.cmd -Passive
}
```

Small caveat: Since the original script file's source code is executed *in memory* in the remote session, *file*-related reflection information won't be available, such as the automatic variables that report a script file's full path and directory path (`$PSCommandPath` and `$PSScriptRoot`).

That said, the same applies to use of the `-FilePath` parameter, which essentially uses the same technique of copying the source code rather than a file to the remote session, behind the scenes.