# Powershell invoke-command ArgumentList with optional argument

Tags: powershell, invoke-command

I have a function that works with the invoke-command function either without any arguments or with all arguments. What I would like to do is run the function via invoke-command with only 1 argument. Here is my code

```
function remove-oldfiles {
param ([String]$days = 28,
[string]$path = "c:\temp\archive")

if ( -not (test-path $path) ) {throw "path not found"}

$cmd = ((Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Recurse |
        where {$_.lastwritetime -lt (get-date).adddays(-$days) -and -not $_.psicontainer}))

$cmd
write-Host("do you want to delete the files? ") -ForegroundColor Red
$ans = (read-host).ToUpper()

if ($ans -eq 'Y') { 
    write-host("deleting files...") 
    $cmd | remove-item -Force
    }
}
```

Both of these commands work:

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName remote_machine -ScriptBlock ${function:remove-oldfiles} -ArgumentList 90, "c:\temp\archive"
Invoke-Command -ComputerName remote_machine -ScriptBlock ${function:remove-oldfiles}
```

But if I try and run it with only 1 argument it doesn't work. Tried:

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName remote_machine -ScriptBlock ${function:remove-oldfiles} -ArgumentList '-path "c:\temp\archive"'
Invoke-Command -ComputerName remote_machine -ScriptBlock ${function:remove-oldfiles} -ArgumentList "c:\temp\archive"
```

Is it possible to use `Invoke-Command` with `-ArgumentList` with just some arguments and not all?

Comment: "Doesn't work" doesn't give us much context to work with. However, the issue is clear, and `Invoke-Command` is not the problem. Your function has 2 parameters, where, positionally the first one is the `$days` parameter, in your second example which "doesn't work" you're passing a path to that parameter.

Comment: `-ArgumentList`: The parameters in the script block are passed by position from the array value supplied to ArgumentList. This is known as _array splatting_.

Answer (score 2):

No, unfortunately **`Invoke-Command` does *not* support passing *named* arguments via `-ArgumentList` / `-Args`**, only *positional* ones - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71253851/45375) for details - and the same goes for other cmdlets that support this parameter, notably `Start-Job` / `Start-ThreadJob` and `Start-Process`.

Therefore, with `-ArgumentList`, in order to bind the `-path` parameter - the *2nd* positional one - you invariably must *also* pass an argument for the *1st* positional one, `-days`.

**Workaround**:

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName remote_machine -ScriptBlock {
  param($funcBody)
  # Here you can use named arguments, as usual.
  # To include values from the caller's scope, use the $using: scope, e.g.,
  # to use the value of local variable $archivePath:
  #  -path $using:archivePath
  & ([scriptblock]::Create($funcBody)) -path c:\temp\archive
} -ArgumentList ${function:remove-oldfiles}
```

Note:

- Even though `${function:remove-oldfiles}` contains the body of function `remove-oldfiles` as a [*script block*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Script_Blocks) in the caller's scope, it turns into a *string* when passed through the remoting de/serialization infrastructure, and must therefore be *rebuilt* as a script block with `[scriptblock]::Create()` in the remote session in order to be callable with `&`.

  - This surprising behavior is discussed in [GitHub issue #11698](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/11698).
- In principle, you should be able to include the function body *directly* in the remotely executing script block, via a [`$using:` reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_scopes#the-using-scope-modifier), namely 
  `${using:function:remove-oldfiles}` in your case  - however, there are two separate bugs that prevent that as of PowerShell Core 7.3.0-preview.2:

  - A *parsing* bug breaks the call if the function name happens to contain `-`, such as in your case.
  - For other function names, such a reference seemingly deserializes to the *empty string* in the remote session.
  - Curiously, `Start-Job`, which also uses the remoting de/serialization infrastructure, does *not* exhibit these problems.

Answer (score 0):

The param() block defines what the `-ArgumentList` passes to the `-ScriptBlock`. You are passing 2 elements into the param block of your function. The variables have assignments as well, which I believe is why the command works without the switch.

In order for the the `-ArgumentList` to accept one argument, you could try to move `$days=28` outside the param block, such that it is still in the scope of the function, such as:

```
  param ([string]$path = "c:\temp\archive")
  $days = 28
```

Comment: thanks for the reply; I'll move the $path outside the param block. The only param I may want to change is days.